# Update array based on other array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I have two arrays

The array `$groeperingen` contains the short codes and the full names and the array `$groep cointains` only shortcodes.

What I want is that all short codes in `$groep` are replaced with the full name.

The array `$groepering` looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [019] => Regio 019a
    [013] => Regio 013
    [011] => Regio alpha
    [AR] => ArmUsers
    [CU] => ComputerUsers
    [GA] => Gamers
    [OP] => Opensource
)
```

The array `$groep` looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => CU
    [1] => GA
    [2] => OP
)
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [array_map](http://php.net/array_map) to apply a function to each element of the `$groep` array.

```
<?php

$groep = Array(
   "CU",
   "GA",
   "OP"
);
$groepering = Array(
   "019" => "Regio 019a",
   "013" => "Regio 013",
   "011" => "Regio alpha",
   "AR" => "ArmUsers",
   "CU" => "ComputerUsers",
   "GA" => "Gamers",                
   "OP" => "Opensource"
);

$result = array_map(function ($x) use ($groepering) {       
   return $groepering[$x];
}, $groep);

print_r($result);
```

The content of `$result` is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => ComputerUsers
    [1] => Gamers
    [2] => Opensource
)
```

See it working here: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/7sv-1kp

Answer (score 0):

This will create a new array.

```
$groeperingen = array(
                  '019' => 'Regio 019a',
                  '013' => 'Regio 013',
                  '011' => 'Regio alpha',
                  'AR' => 'ArmUsers',
                  'CU' => 'ComputerUsers',
                  'GA' => 'Gamers',
                  'OP' => 'Opensource'
                );
$groep = array('CA', 'GA', 'OP');

function changeValue($ary, $basedOnAry){
  foreach($ary as $i => $v){
    $a[$i] = $basedOnAry[$v];
  }
  return $a;
}

$newArray = changeValue($groep, $groeperingen);
```